# capturing both clicks and drags in android

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, touch-event, motionevent

I am overriding both onTouch and onClick. Each is supposed to result in different actions (very important). I don't want a touch to be both a touch and a click: it must be either-or. I am not having much luck. How do I get my app to discriminate between onTouch and onClick? Right now, either I get onTouch by itself or I get both onTouch and onClick together (based on whether I change onTouch to return true or false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to just use `onTouch()`. Look for `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN`. Store the position of the touch in `ACTION_DOWN`, and in `ACTION_UP` if the distance between the touch and the stored touch are < X then fire a custom click event, otherwise fire the drag event.

Comment: Awesome! It just occurred to me to try that. Great minds think alike. I assume it will work. (will let you know if it doesn't).

Comment: Yes, I get you a preemptive check mark. But it does work! Thanks!